# rails not submitting form value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with `text_area`. My problem is that when i click submit, it does not submit the text_area value and leaves it null. I don't know why. Hope someone helps.

SERVER LOGS

```
Started POST "/user/2/posts/2/recommendations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-03 09:14:46 +0200
Processing by RecommendationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "recommendation"=>{"text"=>"hello_world"}, "commit"=>"submit", "user_id"=>"2", "post_id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recommendations_controller.rb:6
  Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recommendations_controller.rb:7
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/recommendations_controller.rb:17
  Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recommendations_controller.rb:17
  recommendation Create (46.9ms)  INSERT INTO "recommendations" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "post_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2018-08-03 07:14:47.832846"], ["updated_at", "2018-08-03 07:14:47.832846"], ["user_id", 2], ["post_id", 2]]
  ↳ app/controllers/recommendations_controller.rb:17
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/recommendations_controller.rb:17
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 141ms (ActiveRecord: 46.9ms)

ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: recommendations.text: INSERT INTO "recommendations" ("created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "post_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)):

app/controllers/recommendations_controller.rb:17:in `create'
```

posts\show.html.erb

```
<%= @post.user.username %>
<%= @post.content %>
    <%= form_for [@user, @post, @recommendation], method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :text %>
      <%= f.submit "submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

*recommendations_controller.rb*

```
class RecommendationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @recommendation = recommendation.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @recommendation = current_user.recommendations.new(permit)
    @recommendation.user_id = @user.id
    @recommendation.post_id = @post.id

    if @recommendation.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: 'back') }
        format.js
      end
    else
      redirect_to 'layouts/404'
    end
  end

  private

  def permit
    params.permit(:text)
  end
end
```

*models/user.rb*

```
has_many :recommendations
```

*models/post.rb*

```
has_many :recommendations
```

*models/recommendation.rb*

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

*schema*

```
create_table "recommendations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text "text", null: false
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "post_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are permitting the params wrongly. You do `params.permit(:text)` but recommendation attributes from your form must be nested inside key `:recommendation` in `params`.

Try changing `permit` (which is not the best name for the method, anyways) to:

```
def permit
  params.require(:recommendation).permit(:text)
end
```

Comment: tried it but I get `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: recommendations):`

Comment: May be you did `params.require(:recommendations)` (plural). Try removing the extra "s".

Comment: how can I not notice this finally after 48 hours this was the problem XD ... thanks a lot

Comment: That's what coding is about. Big problems solved in minutes. Simple problems taking days sometimes. ;)

Comment: @ JagdeepSingh Exactly ... we all learn even from tiny mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

change method with the code below :

```
def permit_params
  params.require(:recommendation).permit(:text)
end

def create
  @user = current_user
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @recommendation=current_user.recommendations.new(permit_params)
  @recommendation.user_id = @user.id
  @recommendation.post_id = @post.id

  if @recommendation.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: 'back') }
      format.js
    end
  else
    redirect_to 'layouts/404'
  end
end
```

Comment: tried it but I get `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: recommendations):`

Comment: @SETHSCHNEIDER did you mistype `recommendation` as `recommendations`?